# Hide Div (toggle) when another is opened

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I implemented a toggle "system" that allows me to present or hide a div with information.

There is a way to just keep one toogle active, that is, I want only one div to appear at a time.

I click on the arrow, to activate the toggle and display the div, if i click on a different line, the previous div line is hidden and I just show the current div.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmlfbf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of Items">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row divCamposEtxra">
        <div (click)="toggle(item)">
            <img *ngIf="item.shown" src="https://img.icons8.com/flat_round/64/000000/collapse-arrow--v1.png" style=" height: 30px;margin-right: 8px;"/>
            <img *ngIf="!item.shown" src="https://img.icons8.com/flat_round/64/000000/expand-arrow--v1.png"  style=" height: 30px;margin-right: 8px;"/>
     </div>
            <div>
                {{item.name}}
            </div>
            <div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right: 12px;">
                {{item.id}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-column" *ngIf="item.shown">
        <span>INFO</span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**.ts**

```
   toggle(item) {
    item.shown = !item.shown;
  }
```

**Problem**

[image]

I just want to open one div at a time, if I press a different one, the previous one is closed / hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update as follows:

Your app component :

```
export class AppComponent  {
  current: number;
  Items=[{
    id:1,
    name:"name",
    shown: false
  },
  {
    id:2,
    name:"name2",
    shown: false
  },
  {
    id:3,
    name:"name3",
    shown: false
  }]

    toggle(item, i) {
    item.shown = !item.shown;
    this.current = i;

  }
}
```

HTML as:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of Items; let i = index">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row divCamposEtxra">
        <!-- <div (click)="toggle(item)"> -->
        <div (click)="toggle(item, i)">
            <img *ngIf="i == current && item.shown" src="https://img.icons8.com/flat_round/64/000000/collapse-arrow--v1.png" style=" height: 30px;margin-right: 8px;"/>
            <img *ngIf="i != current || (i == current && !item.shown)" src="https://img.icons8.com/flat_round/64/000000/expand-arrow--v1.png"  style=" height: 30px;margin-right: 8px;"/>
     </div>
            <div>
                {{item.name}}
            </div>
            <div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right: 12px;">
                {{item.id}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-column" *ngIf="current == i && item.shown">
        <span>TEXTETETETETETETEETETETASDTASDASDHASDJKLASDJASKDJASKLDJAS</span>
        <span>TEXTETETETETETETEETETETASDTASDASDHASDJKLASDJASKDJASKLDJAS</span>
        <span>TEXTETETETETETETEETETETASDTASDASDHASDJKLASDJASKDJASKLDJAS</span>
        <span>TEXTETETETETETETEETETETASDTASDASDHASDJKLASDJASKDJASKLDJAS</span>
        <span>TEXTETETETETETETEETETETASDTASDASDHASDJKLASDJASKDJASKLDJAS</span>
    </div>
    </div>
```